# Suitable method for declaring Array class variables?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am very new to learning Arrays and want to know how to declare variables with scanner inputs using array method. For example, in the regular scenario, lets say I want to find the average of regular scanner inputs I would do something like this:

```
int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
int Average = (num1+num2)/2;
System.out.print(Average);
```

This is the most simple method that I am very familiar with, but I want the same logic/method to be applied with Array class.

**The task** is to Input an integer from the user representing how many more integers are about to be entered.  Then, the user enters the rest of the integers.  The program outputs the average of the numbers, rounded to one decimal place.
Also this is a very simple task but I am unable to declare an **Average** variable based on the example I provided earlier using regular scanner inputs.

My code:

```
else if (option == 2){
    int[] numbers = new int[keyboard.nextInt()];
        for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
            numbers[x] = keyboard.nextInt(); //need to now declare an average variable
        }
    int Average = //What would I put here?
        for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
            System.out.println(Average); //Average needs to be printed
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest a stack

Comment: Use a switch statement

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: You could also use a `Map` (specifically a `HashMap<String, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>>` and add all the operations and their respective functions in that

Comment: Do you want the user to decide first the operation symbol and then do like 2+2+3+5... or the user has to decide after each insertion the operation symbol so he can do this: 2+5-6-2+3... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution...

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result = sc.nextInt();

    while (true) {
        String next = sc.next();

        if (next.equals("done") || next.equals("calculate")) {
            System.out.println(result);
            break; // Exit Loop.
        } else if (next.equals("+")) {
            result += sc.nextInt();
        } else if (next.equals("-")) {
            result -= sc.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unrecognized Input");
            break; // Exit Loop.
        }
    }
}
```

This requires at least one number to be input. Also note, this type of solution will only work for left associative operators. (Luckily both `+` and `-` are) For example, we could not add exponents to this algorithm since the result is calculated in a left associative manor.

Comment: What if you want it to follow BEDMAS?

Comment: I would look up a more complex algorithm. This style program is not good for parentheses or exponents. Beginners often make reverse polish notation calculators using stacks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: Google it. It’s a very popular problem with tons of tutorials and examples. This seems to be a good tutorial for Java for example: https://medium.com/@alonso.delarte/reverse-polish-notation-is-easy-with-test-driven-development-670dfc7bb47c